# What happens in a static parametrized class regarding its instance?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, type-parameter, static-classes

Suppose I have this class:

```
public class DispatcherService<T>
{
    private static Action<T> Dispatcher;

    public static void SetDispatcher(Action<T> action)
    {
        Dispatcher = action;
    }

    public static void Dispatch(T obj)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(obj);
    }
}
```

Let me get this straight... I'll have only one instance of `DispatcherService<T>` for each type, and only when I call it. Right?

Just asking for memory issues.

Comment: (Node that code involving angle brackets *needs* to be 'formatted as code' if you want the angle brackets displayed)

Comment: @AakashM Oh, thanks, I forgot about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'll have only one instance of
>   DispatcherService for each type

Yes.

> and only when I call it. Right?

Yes.

The code is emitted by CLR when it needs to use it.

---

### Note

if I where you I would change it to **singleton**.

```
public class DispatcherService<T>
{

    private static readonly DispatcherService<T> _dispatcher = new DispatcherService<T>();
    private Action<T> _action;

    private DispatcherService() {}

    public static DispatcherService<T> Dispatcher
    {
        get {return _dispatcher ;}
    }

    public void SetDispatcher(Action<T> action)
    {
        Dispatcher = action;
    }

    public void Dispatch(T obj)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the added benefit of Singleton?

Comment: I'm curious as well, what would be the difference?

Comment: Since you are using it as singleton. It is not just a static class containing helper methods, it has got type information. It is a metter of best practices in design.

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many instances of `DispatcherService` as you like, since the class can be instantiated freely. It's another matter that there's no point to that because it has no instance methods. You can change it to `public static class DispatcherService<T>` if it's not meant to be instantiated, as in this example.

You will also have at most one instance of `DispatcherService.Dispatcher` for each type, which is what you probably want to know. If you don't access `DispatcherService` for a specific `T`, no resources will be allocated for that `T`.